# R regex remove unicode apostrophe

Tags: regex, r, unicode, gsub

Lets say I have the following string in R:

`text <- "[Peanut M&M\u0092s]"`

I've been trying to use regex to erase the apostrophe by searching for and deleting `\u0092`:

`replaced <- gsub("\\\\u0092", "", text )`

However, the above doesnt seem to work and results in the same line as the original. What is the correct way to do this removal?

Furthermore, if I wanted to remove the opening and closing `[]`, is it more efficient to do it all in one go or on separate lines?

Comment: Don't know _gsub_ but why not just use hex `\x92`  - Its valid extended ascii. ?

Comment: or `gsub("[][\\\u0092]", '', text )` for better readability

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `[^[:ascii:]]` construct with a Perl-like regex to remove the non-ASCII codes from your input, and you can add an alternative `[][]` to also match square brackets:

```
text <- "[Peanut M&M\u0092s]"
replaced <- gsub("[][]|[^[:ascii:]]", "", text, perl=T)
replaced
## => [1] "Peanut M&Ms"
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/SlYz1B)

If you only plan to remove the `\0092` symbol, you do not need a Perl like regex:

```
replaced <- gsub("[][\u0092]", "", text)
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/7aSr6z)

Note that `[...]` is a character class that matches 1 symbol, here, either a `]` or `[`, or `\u0092`. If you place `]` at the beginning of the character class, it does not need escaping. `[` does not need escaping inside a character class (in R regex and in some other flavors, too).

Comment: Hi, I've tried the first solution and do not get "Peanut M&Ms", it remains: "Peanut M&M\u0092s" second one solves it though. Wiktor could you check results from your first solution one more time? I've entered it into R exactly same script with different results.

Comment: Actually now I wonder if it has something to do with newer versions of R, given this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108790/trouble-with-strings-with-u0092-unicode-characters

Comment: @mkrasmus Make sure the `T` is not redefined, use `perl=TRUE`  always. Not sure what the root cause is.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, as noted, exactly the same command (including the argument perl = TRUE or perl=T) - different results i.e. replaced = "Peanut M&M\u0092s"