# Trouble with strings with <U+0092> Unicode characters

Tags: r, unicode, encoding

I have a very large dataset (70k rows, 2600 columns, CSV format) that I have created by web scraping. Unfortunately, doing the pre-processing, processing etc. at some point some problematic characters have become encoded in an odd way and I have problems dealing with them.

I have strings like the following:

```
x = "but it doesn<U+0092>t matter"
```

[Looking up the code](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/92/index.htm), we can see that it should be the character `’`, which actually should be `'` (the data are user-generated so may contain all kinds of odd characters). Although from looking that character, it seems that others also have problems with it ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571648/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-unicode-character), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030851/jquery-parsejson-u0092-character-is-not-parsed), [3](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/issues/271)). It's labelled a control character, not sure what that is, but perhaps that's why it's so hard to deal with.

Most of the other questions about Unicode in R concern Unicode in the format like this `\u0092`.

### Just use `Encoding()`

Let's try:

```
#> x = "but it doesn<U+0092>t matter"
#> Encoding(x)
#[1] "unknown"
#> Encoding(x) = "UTF-8"
#> Encoding(x)
#[1] "unknown"
#> x
#[1] "but it doesn<U+0092>t matter"
```

So this does not seem to do anything.

### Use the hack functions from these previous questions

There are a few prior questions that concern this Unicode format and try to convert them:

- [Display unicode in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866570/display-unicode-in-r)
- [gsub in R with unicode replacement give different results under Windows compared with Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248457/gsub-in-r-with-unicode-replacement-give-different-results-under-windows-compared?rq=1)

Oddly, the example they give work, but mine doesn't.

```
#> test.string <- "This is a <U+03B1> <U+03B2> <U+03B2> <U+03B3> test <U+03B4> string."
#> Encoding(test.string)
#[1] "unknown"
#> to_true_unicode(test.string)
#[1] "This is a α β β γ test δ string."
```

But:

```
#> x2 = to_true_unicode(x)
#> x2
#[1] "but it doesn\u0092t matter"
#> cat(x2)
#but it doesnt matter
#> Encoding(x2)
#[1] "UTF-8"
```

So, it managed to convert to the `\u` format from the <`U+....>` format, and using `cat()` prints the character without that symbol (or a bugged symbol on SO).

### Just search and replace them manually

I only have a limited number of these problems, so I could perhaps just use search-replace to solve it. However:

```
#> #base-r
#> gsub(x = x, pattern = "<U+0092>", replacement = "'")
#[1] "but it doesn<U+0092>t matter"
#> #stringr/stringi
#> library(stringr)
#> str_replace(x, pattern = "<U+0092>", "'")
#[1] "but it doesn<U+0092>t matter"
```

So replacement does not seem to work, but it does work on the `\u` versions:

```
#> #base-r
#> gsub(x = x2, pattern = "\u0092", replacement = "'")
#[1] "but it doesn't matter"
#> #stringr/stringi
#> library(stringr)
#> str_replace(x2, pattern = "\u0092", "'")
#[1] "but it doesn't matter"
```

So, this suggests a working method: 1) convert `<U+>` format to `\u` format, then use search-replace.

### Unescape with `stringi::stri_unescape_unicode()`

Does not seem to work with either version:

```
#> stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(x)
#[1] "but it doesn<U+0092>t matter"
#> stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(x2)
#[1] "but it doesn\u0092t matter"
```

Is there some generally applicable way to deal with problems like this?

### My setup

My sessionInfo is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5  tools_3.2.3   stringi_1.0-1
```

Running R via RStudio (0.99.893, preview) on Windows 8.1, 64-bit. Keyboard and time-units are Danish, but everything else is in English.

Comment: ¿Could you solve the Issue with R? I'm having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure it will work for you but for the same symptoms i did convert the strings to ascii:

```
x <- iconv(x, "", "ASCII", "byte")
```

For non ascii chars, the indication is `"<xx>"` with the hex code of the byte.

You can then gsub the hex codes to the values that suit you.

Answer (score 5):

I've had a bit of a horrible time with this pernicious little problem, but I think/hope I've finally got somewhere.

After messing around with the `read_csv` options `locale=locale(encoding="xyz")` and trying various combinations of other solutions - the `gsub` solution didn't work, I treid the `stringi` solution...

It didn't work, either. But it has a function `str_enc_detect`, which I ran on the problem values `stri_enc_detect(x)`. It gave me a locale I hadn't tried - in this case windows-1252 - which I promptly set in read_csv options: `locale=locale(encoding = "windows-1252")`

Hey presto it's displaying correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I managed to replace the weird character with the below code example

```
Table$Column[Table$Column== "your weird character"] <- "new character"
```